# Java 8 parallel forEach progress indication

Tags: java, concurrency, lambda, javafx

For performance reason I would like to use a forEach loop of a parallel Lambda stream in order to process an instance of a `Collection` in Java. As this runs in a background `Service` I would like to use the `updateProgress(double,double)` method in order to inform the user about the current progress.

In order to indicate the current progress I need a certain progress indicator in form of a `Integer` counter. However, this is not possible as I can only access `final` variables within the Lambda expression.

Code example see below, `Collection` is only a place holder for any possible instance of a `Collection`:

```
int progress = 0;
Collection.parallelStream().forEach(signer -> {
   progress++;
   updateProgress(progress, Collection.size());     
});
```

I'm aware that I can solve this problem by using a simple for-loop. However, for performance reason it would nice to solve it in this way.

Does anybody know a more or less neat solution to this?

Comment: 1. Why do you think this is actually more performant?  2. I think if this code is actually parallelized, incrementing an integer won't be thread safe; consider AtomicInteger instead.

Comment: There are several [benchmarks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21968918/java-8-nested-loops-with-streams-performance) which showed the performance improvement due to parallelStream. Which is not super surprising when computational intensive tasks are done in parallel. However, you are right that thread-safeness can be an issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As proposed by markspace, using an AtomicInteger is a good solution:

```
AtomicInteger progress = new AtomicInteger();
Collection.parallelStream().forEach(signer -> {
    progress.incrementAndGet();
    // do some other useful work
});
```

I would not use the runLater() variant as your goal is a high performance, and if many parallel threads will generte JavaFX 'runLater' tasks, you will again create a bottleneck...

For the same reason I would NOT call an update to the ProgressBar each time, but use a seaparte JavaFX Timeline to update the progress bar in regular intervals independently from the processing threads.

Here is a full code comparing sequential and parallel processing with ProgressBar. If you remove the sleep(1) and set the number of items to 10 million it will still work concurrently and efficiently...

```
public class ParallelProgress extends Application {
static class ParallelProgressBar extends ProgressBar {
    AtomicInteger myDoneCount = new AtomicInteger();
    int           myTotalCount;
    Timeline      myWhatcher = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(10), e -> update()));

    public void update() {
        setProgress(1.0*myDoneCount.get()/myTotalCount);
        if (myDoneCount.get() >= myTotalCount) {
            myWhatcher.stop();
            myTotalCount = 0;
        }
    }

    public boolean isRunning() { return myTotalCount > 0; }

    public void start(int totalCount) {
        myDoneCount.set(0);
        myTotalCount = totalCount;
        setProgress(0.0);
        myWhatcher.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        myWhatcher.play();
    }

    public void add(int n) {
        myDoneCount.addAndGet(n);
    }
}

HBox testParallel(HBox box) {
    ArrayList<String> myTexts = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int i = 1; i < 10000; i++) {
        myTexts.add("At "+System.nanoTime()+" ns");
    }

    Button runp = new Button("parallel");
    Button runs = new Button("sequential");
    ParallelProgressBar progress = new ParallelProgressBar();

    Label result = new Label("-");

    runp.setOnAction(e -> {
        if (progress.isRunning()) return;
        result.setText("...");
        progress.start(myTexts.size());

        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                long ms = System.currentTimeMillis();
                myTexts.parallelStream().forEach(text -> {
                    progress.add(1);
                    try { Thread.sleep(1);} catch (Exception e1) { }
                });
                Platform.runLater(() -> result.setText(""+(System.currentTimeMillis()-ms)+" ms"));
            }
        }.start();
    });

    runs.setOnAction(e -> {
        if (progress.isRunning()) return;
        result.setText("...");
        progress.start(myTexts.size());
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                final long ms = System.currentTimeMillis();
                myTexts.forEach(text -> {
                    progress.add(1);
                    try { Thread.sleep(1);} catch (Exception e1) { }
                });
                Platform.runLater(() -> result.setText(""+(System.currentTimeMillis()-ms)+" ms"));
            }
        }.start();
    });

    box.getChildren().addAll(runp, runs, progress, result);
    return box;
}


@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {        
    primaryStage.setTitle("ProgressBar's");

    HBox box = new HBox();
    Scene scene = new Scene(box,400,80,Color.WHITE);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);

    testParallel(box);

    primaryStage.show();   
}

public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
}
```

Comment: Nice solution. It should also be noted that this is more efficient only when the frequency of progress updates is faster than 10 milliseconds.

Comment: jupp, that's correct... if the tasks computed in parallel are 'heavy' this is somehow 'overdriven'. But if the tasks are highly parallel (MANY cores) and small (tousands to millions per second) this gets useful...

Answer (score 1):

The naive solution would be to have progress as a field of some surrounding object; then referring to `progress` from a lambda closure would actually mean `this.progress`, where `this` is `final`, thus the compiler would not complain. However, the resulting code would access the `progress` field from multiple threads concurrently, which could cause race conditions. I suggest restricting access to the `progress` field to the JavaFX application thread, by using `Platform.runLater`. The whole solution then looks like this:

```
// accessed only on JavaFX application thread
private int progress = 0;

// invoked only on the JavaFX application thread
private void increaseProgress() {
    progress++;
    updateProgress(progress, collection.size());
}

private void processCollection() {
    collection.parallelStream().forEach(signer -> {
        // do the work (on any thread)
        // ...

        // when done, update progress on the JavaFX thread
        Platfrom.runLater(this::increaseProgress);
    });
}
```