# Why does skip() in this parallel stream expression in Java 19 cause an OOM even with 8GB?

Tags: java, java-stream, parallelstream

I get an OOM in Java 19 even with 8GB if I do this:

```
IntStream
.iterate(0, i -> i + 1)
.skip(2)
.limit(10_000_000)
.filter(i -> checkSum(i) <= 20)
.parallel()
.count();
```

However, I don't get any OOM if I omit skip(2):

```
IntStream
.iterate(0, i -> i + 1)
//.skip(2)
.limit(10_000_000)
.filter(i -> checkSum(i) <= 20)
.parallel()
.count();
```

where checksum(...) is

```
public static long checkSum(long n) {
    long result = 0;
    long remaining = n;
    while (0 < remaining) {
        long remainder = remaining % 10;
        result += remainder;
        remaining = (remaining - remainder) / 10;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Why does skip() in this parallel stream expression in Java 19 cause an OOM even with 8GB?

I know I should use range(...) instead of iterate()+limit() with or without skip().
However, that doesn't answer me this question. I would like to understand what's the issue here.

Comment: Order of operations is important. Move the `skip(2)` down a line, and it will work.

Comment: If you do not want to use `.range(...)` (because maybe the number you want are irregular), you can `limit` already on the `iterate`: `....iterate(0, i -> i < 10_000_002, i -> i + 1)...`

Comment: I know the order is important. And yes, it works if skip() comes AFTER limit() even if it changes the result a bit here. However, I don't understand why skip() before limit() leads to a OOM. I would only have expected it hanging up.

Comment: Hmm... the behaviour seems only partially related to `skip(...)`. It is also influenced by `parallel()` (removing `....paralllel()...` also prevents the `Exception`)....

Comment: this seems pretty closely related: [Java 8, using .parallel in a stream causes OOM error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30825708/java-8-using-parallel-in-a-stream-causes-oom-error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`skip()` - is a ***stateful*** operation which guarantees that `n` **first** elements of the stream (*with respect of the encounter order, if the stream is ordered*) would be omitted.

It would be cheap in a sequential pipeline, but might be costful while running in parallel if the stream is ordered. [Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#skip(long)) warns about that and suggests loosening the constraint ordering if possible.

> **API Note:**
>
> While `skip()` is generally a cheap operation on sequential stream pipelines, it **can be quite expensive on ordered parallel pipelines**,
> especially for large values of `n`, since `skip(n)` is constrained to skip
> not just any n elements, but the first n elements in the encounter
> order. Using an unordered stream source (such as `generate(Supplier)`)
> or removing the ordering constraint with `BaseStream.unordered()` may
> result in significant speedups of `skip()` in parallel pipelines, if the
> semantics of your situation permit. If consistency with encounter
> order is required, and you are experiencing poor performance or memory
> utilization with `skip()` in parallel pipelines, switching to sequential
> execution with `BaseStream.sequential()` may improve performance.

<sup>Emphasis added</sup>

The following unordered Stream would run without issues (*result of the stream execution might not be consistent because in unordered stream threads a free to discard any `n` elements, not `n` first*):

```
IntStream
    .iterate(0, i -> i + 1)
    .unordered()
    .skip(2)
    .limit(10_000_000)
    .filter(i -> checkSum(i) <= 20)
    .parallel()
    .count();
```