# What is the best/efficient way to convert HashSet of type String to HashSet of type Long

Tags: java, collections

What is the best/efficient way to convert HashSet of type `<String>` to HashSet of type `<Long>` ?

Comment: may be by trying out some actual code? try lambda expressions from java 8. would give you the solution in single line

Answer (score 3):

```
Set<Long> longSet = stringSet.stream().map(s-> Long.parseLong(s))
                             .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

I haven't tried it out but should work

Comment: `s-> Long.parseLong(s)` could be a method reference: `Long::parseLong`.

Answer (score 0):

An improvement to sidgate's answer [when working with really large sets]: you can use parallelStream() it should be more efficient on large set, and replace Long.parseLong(s) with method reference.

```
Set<Long> longSet = stringSet.parallelStream()
                .map(Long::parseLong)
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

[Edit] As noted in the comments, use parallelStream() only when working with really large sets, as it adds considerable amount of overhead.

[More on the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20375622/4405343)

Comment: `parallelStream` though useful, shouldn't be used for such simpler use case. http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/java-parallel-streams-are-bad-for-your-health/

Comment: No, don't use `parallelStream` unless you have more than 10,000-100,000 elements and have measured that using `parallelStream` will be an improvement.

Comment: You're both right, I'll edit the answer to stress the fact.