# Java-8 simplify lambda expression with embedded Streams

Tags: java-8, java-stream

Is there a more simple and performant way of doing this, At the end I would need a list of `scheduleContainers (List<ScheduleContainer>)`

```
final List<ScheduleResponseContent> scheduleResponseContents = new ArrayList<>();
scheduleResponseWrappers.parallelStream().forEach(srw -> scheduleResponseContents.addAll(srw.getScheduleResponseContents()));
final List<List<ScheduleContainer>> schedulesOfWeek = new ArrayList<>();
scheduleResponseContents.parallelStream().forEach(src -> schedulesOfWeek.addAll(src.getSchedules()));
final List<ScheduleContainer> schedules = new ArrayList<>();
schedulesOfWeek.parallelStream().forEach(s -> schedules.addAll(s));
```

Comment: you need a list which combines all of your list results?

Comment: You absolutely need to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20375176/should-i-always-use-a-parallel-stream-when-possible. Not only your code shouldn't use parallel streams because it's unnecessary, but worse: it's not thread-safe.

Comment: Augh!  Your code is totally not thread-safe; you're cramming stuff in parallel into a poor helpless `ArrayList`.  You need to immediately get out of your habit of using `parallelStream` by default.

Comment: It seems you're looking for flatMap().

Comment: And use `collect()` instead of `forEach()`.

Answer (score 1):

Because of missing classes, I can just assume this is correct:

```
final List<ScheduleContainer> schedules = scheduleResponseWrappers.stream()
    .flatMap(srw -> srw.getScheduleResponseContents().stream())
    .flatMap(src -> src.getSchedules().stream())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```