# Fastest way to convert key value pairs to grouped by key objects map using java 8 stream

Tags: performance, collections, java-8, java-stream

Model:

```
public class AgencyMapping {
    private Integer agencyId;
    private String scoreKey;
}

public class AgencyInfo {
    private Integer agencyId;
    private Set<String> scoreKeys;
}
```

My code:

```
List<AgencyMapping> agencyMappings;
 Map<Integer, AgencyInfo> agencyInfoByAgencyId = agencyMappings.stream()
            .collect(groupingBy(AgencyMapping::getAgencyId,
                    collectingAndThen(toSet(), e -> e.stream().map(AgencyMapping::getScoreKey).collect(toSet()))))
            .entrySet().stream().map(e -> new AgencyInfo(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(AgencyInfo::getAgencyId, identity()));
```

Is there a way to get the same result and use more simpler code and faster?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simplify the call to `collectingAndThen(toSet(), e -> e.stream().map(AgencyMapping::getScoreKey).collect(toSet()))))` with a call to `mapping(AgencyMapping::getScoreKey, toSet())`.

```
Map<Integer, AgencyInfo> resultSet = agencyMappings.stream()
                .collect(groupingBy(AgencyMapping::getAgencyId,
                        mapping(AgencyMapping::getScoreKey, toSet())))
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .map(e -> new AgencyInfo(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
                .collect(toMap(AgencyInfo::getAgencyId, identity()));
```

A different way to see it using a `toMap` collector:

```
Map<Integer, AgencyInfo> resultSet = agencyMappings.stream()
                .collect(toMap(AgencyMapping::getAgencyId, // key extractor
                        e -> new HashSet<>(singleton(e.getScoreKey())), // value extractor
                        (left, right) -> { // a merge function, used to resolve collisions between values associated with the same key
                            left.addAll(right);
                            return left;
                        }))
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .map(e -> new AgencyInfo(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
                .collect(toMap(AgencyInfo::getAgencyId, identity()));
```

The latter example is arguably more complicated than the former. Nevertheless, your approach is pretty much the way to go apart from using `mapping` as opposed to `collectingAndThen` as mentioned above.

Apart from that, I don't see anything else you can simplify with the code shown.

As for *faster* code, if you're suggesting that your current approach is slow in performance then you may want to read the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20375176/should-i-always-use-a-parallel-stream-when-possible) that speak about when you should consider going parallel.

Comment: Thanks, for suggestion with:   mapping(AgencyMapping::getScoreKey, toSet())))

Answer (score 1):

You are collecting to an intermediate map, then streaming the entries of this map to create `AgencyInfo` instances, which are finally collected to another map.

Instead of all this, you could use [`Collectors.toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) to collect directly to a map, mapping each `AgencyMapping` object to the desired `AgencyInfo` and merging the `scoreKeys` as needed:

```
Map<Integer, AgencyInfo> agencyInfoByAgencyId = agencyMappings.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
            AgencyMapping::getAgencyId,
            mapping -> new AgencyInfo(
                    mapping.getAgencyId(), 
                    new HashSet<>(Set.of(mapping.getScoreKey()))),
            (left, right) -> {
                left.getScoreKeys().addAll(right.getScoreKeys());
                return left;
            }));
```

This works by grouping the `AgencyMapping` elements of the stream by `AgencyMapping::getAgencyId`, but storing `AgencyInfo` objects in the map instead. We get these `AgencyInfo` instances from manually mapping each original `AgencyMapping` object. Finally, we're merging `AgencyInfo` instances that are already in the map by means of a *merge function* that *folds left* `scoreKeys` from one `AgencyInfo` to another.

I'm using Java 9's `Set.of` to create a singleton set. If you don't have Java 9, you can replace it with `Collections.singleton`.

Comment: more than welcome mate!. your saying of “singletonSet” was understandable though considering there is also “singletonList” and “singletonMap”. It feels inconsistent that they didn’t call it “singletonSet”.

Comment: @Aominè Actually, I remember a question asking exactly about that inconsistency. The answer was something like *by definition, a singleton is a set that consists of only one element* (with a link to wikipedia included). And the guy who had asked responded something like *yeah, I know, but why the incosistency in the name?* and someone responded in a not-very-nice way saying that you don't say a singleton set, because set is implicit in singleton, etc, etc, etc. It was quite fun (for about 20 seconds)...