# Make an iterative multi-threaded method

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist, java-8, duplicates

I have a method named `find_duplicates(List<DP> dp_list)` which takes an ArrayList of my custom data type DP. Each DP has a String named 'ID' which should be unique for each DP.

My method goes through the whole list and adds any DP which does not have a unique ID to another ArrayList, which is returned when the method finishes. It also changes a boolean field `isUnique` of the DP from true to false.

I want to make this method multi-threaded, since each check of an element is independent of other elements' checks. But for each check the thread would need to read the dp_list. Is it possible to give the read access of the same List to different threads at the same time? Can you suggest a method to make it multithreaded?

Right now my code looks like this-

```
List<DP> find_duplicates(List<DP> dp_list){
    List<DP> dup_list = new ArrayList<>();
    for(DP d: dp_list){
        -- Adds d to dup_list and sets d.isUnique=false if d.ID is not unique --
    }
    return dup_list;
}
```

Comment: Look at Streams

Comment: You can use java-8 parallel stream

Answer (score 1):

```
List<DP> unique = dp_list.stream().parallel().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Then just find the difference between the original list and the list of unique elements and you have your duplicates.

Obviously you will need a filter if your items are only unique by one of their fields - a quick SO search for "stream distinct by key" can provide a myriad of ways to do that.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you want to leverage parallelism where possible. First and foremost I'd suggest measuring your code whether that is with an imperative approach or using a sequential stream *and then* if you think by going parallel can *really* help improve performance then you can use a parallel stream. [see here to help decide when to use a parallel stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20375176/should-i-always-use-a-parallel-stream-when-possible).

As for accomplishing the task at hand, it can be done as follows:

```
List<DP> find_duplicates(List<DP> dp_list){
        List<DP> dup_list = dp_list.stream() //dp_list.parallelStream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(DP::getId))
                .values()
                .stream()
                .filter(e -> e.size() > 1)
                .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        dup_list.forEach(s -> s.setUnique(false));
        return dup_list;
}
```

This will create a stream from the source then groups the elements by their ids and retains all the elements that have a duplicate id and then finally sets the `isUnique` field to `false`;

Answer (score 0):

There are better ways in which you can do this.
All you need to do is get the lock of the `list` and check if item exists followed by further processing.

```
void find_duplicates(List<DP> dp_list, DP item){

    synchronized(dp_list){
        if(dp_list.contains(item)){
            //Set your flags
        }
    }


}
```