# How large should my list of objects be to warrant the use of java 8's parallelStream?

Tags: java, parallel-processing, stream, java-stream

I have a list of objects from the database and i want to filter this list using the `filter()` method of the `Stream` class. New objects will be added to the database continuously so the list of objects could potentially become very large, possibly thousands of objects. I want to use a `parallelStream` to speed up the filter process but i was wondering how large the object list should approximately be to make the use of parallelStream benificial. I've read this thread about it: [Should I always use a parallel stream when possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20375176/should-i-always-use-a-parallel-stream-when-possible)
And in this thread they agree that the dataset should be really large if you want to have any benefit from using a parallel stream. But how large is large? Say I have 200 records stored in my database and i retrieve them all for filtering, is using a parallelstream justified in this case? If not, how large should the dataset be? a 1000? 2000 perhaps? I'd love to know. Thank you.

Comment: Probably in ten to hundrend thousands, if not even millions, but it really depends on the actions you want to make

Comment: Check this question out - the accepted answer should help:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20375176/should-i-always-use-a-parallel-stream-when-possible

Comment: The best answer is: it depends. You must test it. I found that the performance depends on what you are trying to do and on the computer(-processors) it is running.

Comment: [it might be helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20375176/should-i-always-use-a-parallel-stream-when-possible)

Comment: The formula at the bottom of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39066952/5515060) may help

Comment: @Lino its just for filtering. No other actions

Comment: In the second (and third) answer of the question you linked by Brian Goetz he talks about the NQ model, where N is the amount and Q the computation per element. So as mentioned by @Lino it really depends on what each iteration does. For low-Q computations it can indeed be in the millions, but for high-Q computations it could only be a couple thousand. Unfortunately there isn't a clear answer. It depends on what you want to do, and after that it's basically doing different kind of performance tests.

Comment: well its just for filtering so thats not really CPU intensive i suppose. Guess i'll go with the sequential stream then

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/html/StreamParallelGuidance.html) and depending on the operation it would require at least 10_000, but not elements; instead **N * Q** where `N = number of elements` and `Q = cost per element`.

But this is a general formula you push against, without measuring this is close to impossible to say (read guess here); proper tests will prove you wrong or right.

For some simple operations, it is *almost* never the case when you would actually need parallel processing for the purpose of speed-up.

Some other things to mention here, is that this heavily depends on the source - how easy it is to split. Anything array-based or index-based are easy to split (and fast), but a `Queue` or lines from a `File` do not, so you will probably lose more time splitting rather than computing, unless, of course, there are enough elements to cover for this. And *enough* is something you actually measure.

Answer (score 0):

from '[Modern java in Action](https://www.manning.com/books/modern-java-in-action?gclid=CjwKCAjw2P-KBhByEiwADBYWCuvnXL6YnygfwItxEP7iZuARL3a59WDOF1JqiRlkHTXQVtKgSFOiwRoCsjwQAvD_BwE)':
"Although it may seem odd at first, often the fastest way to filter
a collection...is to convert it to a stream, process it in parallel, and then convert it back to a list"