# Execute runnables in a list

Tags: java, java-8

I have a list of runnables that I would like to call using lambda expressions:

```
Arrays.asList(runnable1, runnable2, runnable3, ...).forEach(r->r.run());
```

Is there a 'better' (more efficient) shortcut to call the `Runnable`s `run()` method other than the following way?

```
Arrays.asList(runnable1, runnable2, runnable3, ...).forEach(Runnable::run);
```

I think this expression will be translated to a `Runnable` wrapping the runnable instance in the list.

EDIT:
My assumption/concern (maybe wrong) is that the compiler will translate the expression `list.forEach(Runnable::run)` to something like this, and thus not 'efficient':

```
list.forEach(r -> new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            r.run();
        }
    });
```

Comment: There is no wrapping here. You already have instances of ``Runnable``, each of them has the ``run`` method invoked. But this happens sequentially, not in parallel (which you might expect because ``Runnable``s often show up in conjunction with threads).

Comment: No, it's a statement (note that `List.forEach` is `void`).

Comment: "Efficient" in what sense?

Comment: After your edit: No, it doesn't. The ``Runnable`` is not wrapped, ``run`` is called on your original instances. Your first two snippets are effectively the same.

Comment: Why should  *new* `Runnable`s be created? Those already exist, their method `run` will be called.

Comment: @erdal.karaca Runnable::run is just a shorter version for calling the run method of a Runnable interface. It will not be wrapped, why would it be wrapped?

Comment: @erdal.karaca Anyway, you might think of using a parallel stream if it suits your needs: `Stream.of(arrayOfRunnables).parallel().forEach(Runnable:run);`
More details about when to use a pallel stream can be found here: [Should i always use a parallel stream when possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20375176/should-i-always-use-a-parallel-stream-when-possible)

Comment: Thanks, guys, for the comments: My question was based on wrong assumptions. Will close the question as invalid. Or if you can answer with a link to the lang specs I can read to get more clarification, I will accept it.

Comment: @erdal.karaca If you are facing performance issues, and that is the reason why you were asking this question, my other comment could help you.

Comment: @TothLudovicAndreas: just wanted know if the compiler would create redundant wrapping objects when using a method pointer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether you write

```
Arrays.asList(runnable1, runnable2, runnable3, ...).forEach(r->r.run());
```

or

```
Arrays.asList(runnable1, runnable2, runnable3, ...).forEach(Runnable::run);
```

in either case, there will be an instance of **`Consumer`** generated, as that’s what `Iterable.forEach` expects.

The consumer will be *equivalent* to

```
Arrays.asList(runnable1, runnable2, runnable3, ...).forEach(new Consumer<Runnable>() {
    public void accept(Runnable r) {
        r.run();
    }
});
```

but that’s not a wrapper around a runnable, as it encapsulates an action applied to arbitrary `Runnable` instances passed in as parameter. Hence, there is at most one `Consumer` instance created for the entire `forEach` operation.

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27524543/2711488), the JVM will be responsible for the creation of the `Consumer` instance and has the freedom to reuse existing instances, which happens in practice with the current implementation and *non-capturing* instances of functional interfaces, which applies to both variants, using a lambda expression or a method reference, so there will be only one `Consumer` instance, reused even on subsequent evaluations of the statement.

The only difference with current compilers is that the lambda expression `r->r.run()` will generate a method within your class calling the `run()` method whereas for the method reference, the runtime generated `Consumer` implementation class will call it directly, which makes the method reference more efficient on the *hard-to-ever-measure* scale.