# Stream anyMatch failing with "Incompatible types" error

Tags: java, java-stream

I want to print the contacts from my given set by number and I'm trying to do it with streams. With a little googling i saw people solving it the way I'm trying right now. But I'm getting this error `Incompatible types: PhoneNumber is not convertible to CharSequence` and i don't understand what i need to do. The error is in the method `contactsByNumber`
Code:
**PhoneNumber.java**

```
class PhoneNumber {

   private String name;
   private String number;

   public PhoneNumber(String name, String number) {
       this.name = name;
       this.number = number;
   }

   public String getName() {
       return name;
   }

   public String getNumber() {
       return number;
   }
}
```

**PhoneBook**

```
class PhoneBook {
    private Set<PhoneNumber> phoneNumbers;

    public PhoneBook() {
        this.phoneNumbers = new HashSet<>();
    }

    public void addContact(String name, String number) throws DuplicateNumberException {
        PhoneNumber pn = new PhoneNumber(name, number);
        if(phoneNumbers.contains(pn)) {
            throw new DuplicateNumberException(number);
         } else {
             phoneNumbers.add(new PhoneNumber(name, number));
         }
     }

     public void contactsByNumber(String number) {
          phoneNumbers.stream().parallel().anyMatch(number::contains);
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In this section:

```
public void contactsByNumber(String number) {
    phoneNumbers.stream().parallel().anyMatch(number::contains);
}
```

it is a `Stream<PhoneNumber>`, and you are trying to treat it as a `String`. You need to map it to it's `name` attribute:

```
public void contactsByNumber(String number) {
    phoneNumbers.stream().parallel().map(PhoneNumber::getName).anyMatch(number::contains);
}
```

However this method does nothing, as you ignore the result of `anyMatch`. If you wanted to print the results, you could change `anyMatch` to `filter` and then print:

```
public void contactsByNumber(String number) {
    phoneNumbers.stream()
                .parallel()
                .map(PhoneNumber::getName)
                .filter(number::contains)
                .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

---

Also if you don't have a good reason to use a `parallel` Stream, I would recommend not using one, as [it has a lot more overhead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20375622/8534008)

Comment: Thank you for explaining it in detail so i will know next time appreciate it!