# Seeking Optimization Suggestions for Map-to-Map Conversion

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap, hashset

I'm seeking feedback as to whether there's a more efficient approach than what I'm doing in my code shown at the bottom.

Basically, given this map:

```
        Set<String> A_Set = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("1111", "2222", "5555"));
        Set<String> B_Set = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("3333", "4444"));
        Set<String> C_Set = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("6666"));
        Set<String> D_Set = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("2222", "5555", "6666"));

        Map<String, Set<String>> values = new HashMap<>();
        values.put("A", A_Set);
        values.put("B", B_Set);
        values.put("C", C_Set);
        values.put("D", D_Set);
```

which looks like this:

[image]

How do I create a `Map<String, List<Boolean> map` such that it looks like this:

[image]

In the **most efficient** way possible. My real `Map` has thousands of values per `Set`, but there are only ever 4 `Sets` (A, B, C, D).

Here's my current code. Can you think of a more efficient approach?

```
import java.util.*;

public class MapToMap {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<String> A_Set = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("1111", "2222", "5555"));
        Set<String> B_Set = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("3333", "4444"));
        Set<String> C_Set = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("6666"));
        Set<String> D_Set = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("2222", "5555", "6666"));

        Map<String, Set<String>> values = new HashMap<>();
        values.put("A", A_Set);
        values.put("B", B_Set);
        values.put("C", C_Set);
        values.put("D", D_Set);

        Map<String, List<Boolean>> exists = new HashMap<>();

        for (Map.Entry<String, Set<String>> v : values.entrySet()) {
            for (String val : v.getValue()) {
                if (exists.containsKey(val)) {
                    List<Boolean> list = exists.get(val);
                    list = addValue(v.getKey(), list);
                    exists.put(val, list);
                } else {
                    List<Boolean> newList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(false, false, false, false));
                    newList = addValue(v.getKey(), newList);
                    exists.put(val, newList);
                }
            }
        }
        for (Map.Entry<String, List<Boolean>> s : exists.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }

    private static List<Boolean> addValue(String key, List<Boolean> listToUse) {
        List<Boolean> newList = new ArrayList<>();
        if (Objects.equals("A", key)) {
            newList.addAll(Arrays.asList(true, listToUse.get(1), listToUse.get(2), listToUse.get(3)));
        } else if (Objects.equals("B", key)) {
            newList.addAll(Arrays.asList(listToUse.get(0), true, listToUse.get(2), listToUse.get(3)));
        } else if (Objects.equals("C", key)) {
            newList.addAll(Arrays.asList(listToUse.get(0), listToUse.get(1), true, listToUse.get(3)));
        } else if (Objects.equals("D", key)) {
            newList.addAll(Arrays.asList(listToUse.get(0), listToUse.get(1), listToUse.get(2), true));
        }
        return newList;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the key the number or the letter?

Comment: Do your 4 keys are known beforehand?

Comment: If the code is working, then this belongs on [codereview.se]

Comment: @Manh yes, the keys (A,B,C,D) are known before hand. The values of the sets (ex: 1111, 2222, etc.) are *not* known beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using streams:

```
Map<String, List<Boolean>> exists = values.values()
        .stream()
        .flatMap(Set::stream)
        .distinct()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(v -> v, v -> Stream.of("A", "B", "C", "D")
                .map(k -> values.get(k).contains(v))
                .collect(Collectors.toList())));
```

[**Ideone Demo**](https://ideone.com/mgQ6I1)

Comment: thank you but it appears Streams take twice as long (6 seconds vs. 3 seconds for non-streams) in my test here: https://ideone.com/2XZygo

Comment: Try parallel streams.

Comment: I'm quite hesitant to implement parallelism given the expertise on the topic here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23370799/4731712 advising:  `But the reality is quite complicated. So until you achieve experthood, first identify when sequential processing is actually costing you something, and then measure if parallelism will help.` I don't want to prematurely optimize an algorithm that might not need it. I was seeking simple improvements on my code but I don't think there's much "easy" room for improvement, appreciate your time.

Comment: The whole question was how to optimize your code. How is this premature?

Comment: Perhaps that was the wrong term, but given the expertise seemingly required to successfully `(1)` identify if parallelism is required and `(2)` ensuring its implemented appropriately is outside the scope of what I'm seeking. I'm not saying it won't help, but I can't justify the investment to find out. Especially given Brian's expertise advice quoted in the next comment.

Comment: `It is best to develop first using sequential execution and then apply parallelism where (A) you know that there's actually benefit to increased performance and (B) that it will actually deliver increased performance. (A) is a business problem, not a technical one. If you are a performance expert, you'll usually be able to look at the code and determine (B), but the smart path is to measure. (And, don't even bother until you're convinced of (A); if the code is fast enough, better to apply your brain cycles elsewhere.)`

Comment: I haven't accepted your current answer as it does not optimize my code, just FYI. Thanks regardless, you've put parallelism on my radar and helped me understand streams better.

Comment: It sounds to me like you're making exactly the type of mistake Brian is warning against, namely, making blanket assumptions without considering the particulars of a case. Let's look at his closing statement: *So until you achieve experthood, first identify when sequential processing is actually costing you something, and then measure if parallelism will help.* Is sequential processing costing you something? It certainly seems so. Did you measure if parallelism will help? If you do, and it does help, why would you not want to use it? This is practically a case study in when to try parallelism.

Comment: I think you're exaggerating the level of expertise required to test parallelism. It's literally one line of code. The whole streams infrastructure was designed to provide parallelism out of the box, as long as you're doing everything by the book. It would be a shame to give up that power without a compelling reason.

Comment: `Did you measure if parallelism will help? If you do, and it does help, why would you not want to use it?` I interpreted his point (A) above meaning don't optimize your code with parallel streams until you can test it in a business setting, as it's not a purely technical issue (one line of code added).I'd need to test on real servers, with real clients and load. I'm simply in developing mode and don't want to invest time into something that may not be an issue in reality. You're convincing me to ..

Comment: Not brush over the potential performance enhancements and invest more time to understand how it may help or hinder. If it so happens that I see an improvement then I'll come back and accept.

Comment: *don't optimize your code with parallel streams until you can test it in a business setting...* Fair point. I assumed your test roughly corresponded to your real-world needs. But if it doesn't, any potential solution carries a similar risk. Optimization is always a delicate process, whether or not it involves parallelism.