# using parallelStream for independent tasks?

Tags: java, java-stream, vert.x

I have a list of tasks. Each task is **independent** of each other (they do not use results from each other).

When having 1000 tasks and using a sequential stream to process these tasks..

```
tasks.forEach(task->{
            // long running task
            task.run();
            System.out.println("Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        });
```

..then, the second task is running AFTER the first task and so forth. The loop is running in blocking and sequential mode (second task is only done after first task is finished).

**What is the best way to process each task in parallel?**

Is this the best way?

```
tasks.parallelStream().forEach(task->{
            // long running task
            task.run();
            System.out.println("Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        });
```

According to [Should I always use a parallel stream when possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20375176/should-i-always-use-a-parallel-stream-when-possible), it should be avoided to use parallel streams. As in my case, these tasks are **independent** of each other, I do not need the **synchronization overhead** which comes by using `parallelStream()`. However, there is no option to disable the synchronization overhead when using `parallelStream()`. Or?

Is there a better way for my use case than `parallelStream()`?

Comment: Why not submit your tasks to an `ExecutorService`? Then you can also specifiy how much threads should be used for parallel processing.

Comment: To clarify: "synchronization overhead" just means *it's expensive to do the things necessary to run multiple things in parallel*. It's not about "need", it's just *the cost you must pay to parallelize*. Parallelizing is only worthwhile if the *savings* from parallel execution outweigh the *costs* of setting up parallel execution

Comment: Why should I use fork-join-techniques when my tasks are independent of each other? I guess, the "synchronization overhead" is the **join**-part which I do not need for my case. I only want to use async and non-blocking processing of each task without synchronization..

Comment: It's not just the synchronization of the tasks themselves, but the synchronization required to schedule and execute the tasks. Blocking tasks need special coordination with the thread pool, and very fast tasks don't benefit from parallelism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good solution for you can be to use [`CompletableFuture.allOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#allOf-java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture...-). Use it like this:

```
ExecutorService ex = //Whatever executor you want;

CompletableFuture.allOf((CompletableFuture<Void>[]) tasks.stream()
        .map(task -> CompletableFuture.runAsync((() -> /* Do task */), ex))
        .toArray());
```

In doing so, you can perform asynchronous, non-blocking. Also, you will get a compiler warning about type casting but I think in your case, it may be safe to ignore it.

`ExecutorService.submit` will fire off the task but when you use `get` to obtain any result, it's going to block and then retrieve. `CompletableFuture` doesn't block when getting the data. This is case when you want to see some kind of result returned after all the parallel tasks finish.
Some more explanation can be found [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-completablefuture#Multiple).

Also, in your original question, you asked if it is a good idea to use `parallelStream` and my answer to that would be that it isn't a good idea because if there is a task that blocks the thread then you will have problems (assuming you have used `parallelStream` all over the place in your code).

Also, `CompletableFuture` can accept it's own thread pool (which you can customize yourself) and run there. Notice the second argument to `runAsync` in the above code.

If you simply want to have a fire and forget mechanism and don't care about the result then using the [`ExecutorService.invokeAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll(java.util.Collection)) is a good way to do thing. You can use it like this:

```
 executorService.invokeAll(tasks.stream().map(task -> new Callable<Void>() {
                @Override
                public Void call() throws Exception {
                    // run task;
                    return null;
                }
            })
.collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

But why do you want to use a `CompletableFuture` with your own `ExecutorService` in such a case?
One good reason is the fluent error handling. You can see some examples [here](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/core-java-tutorial/java-multi-threading/completion-stages-exception-handling.html) and [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-completablefuture#Handling)

Comment: Can u tell me the difference between yours and the following version: 
`tasks.forEach(u -> executorService.submit(t::run));` Why should I use CompletableFuture additionally?

Comment: According to https://dzone.com/articles/concurrency-in-action-using-javas-completable-futu: `CompletableFuture` uses a forkjoin thread pool, which is a thread pool **shared between all CompletableFutures and all parallel streams**. I did not get the point: why not  simply using my above solution with `tasks.parallelStream()` as it also uses forkjoin thread pool..it seems, there is no benefit in using `CompletableFuture` over `parallelStream`..both are async and non-blocking..or?

Comment: And what if I use `ExecutorService.submit` **without** using `get` and without `CompletableFuture`. I do not need a result, it should only process the task (like fire and forget). Does this behave non blocking and async the same as if I would use `CompletableFuture` in combination with `ExecutorService`?

Comment: @nimo23 is it compulsory for you to collect all your tasks in a `List`? What I mean is that is it possible for you to use the result of the computation directly in the other executor and not collect it in a `List`?

Answer (score 3):

In Java 8 `parallelStream()` use the `ForkJoinCommonPool` which is initialised at JVM startup and contains a fixed number of threads that is more suited to work that can follows the "divide and conquer" paradigm. In your case, since they are all isolated, the use of an `ExecutorService` may be more fitting.

Comment: Can I **nest** executorServices? For example: Actually, the `tasks`-list is produced by a `scheduledExecutorService` and after the task-list is produced, I delegate each task to `executorService`. After all tasks are finished, it waits for the next schedule. And repeat these steps. Are there any caveats when nesting an `executorService` within a `scheduledExecutorService`? Or are there better techniques for such cases?

Comment: You mean having a single thread that generates tasks every X minutes/seconds etc and then passes these to an Executor Service that has a predefined number of threads? It's not exactly **nesting** because they operate independently, it's just so happens that your scheduled service utiilises the fixed service. Without knowing too much of the task you're trying to acomplish I'd say it seems ok.

Comment: I already tried it and it works..however, I tend to use CompletableFuture with ExecutorService as it is more like "fire and forget" (non-blocking and async) which is what I need.

Comment: Yeah and you can check the state of those Futures to see if it's finished. If they're not you could block the Scheduler Service until they've finished (which I think you said you wanted when you said "after all tasks are finished") because if they've not finished and you're Scheduler Service goes over the next schedule then it will just queue the new tasks

Comment: I guess, I do not need to see if its finished, because I use `executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay`..so it must process all tasks and only after all previous tasks finished it will run the next schedule.

Comment: But I thought you said you had 2 executors? 1 that's the scheduled one (The line you just gave: `executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay`) and another (fixed one) that receives the tasks to perform. Your schedule one will be giving the fixed one tasks asynchronously and **won't** wait for them to finish before scheduling again... That's why I suggested that the logic in your schedule one needs to check to see if the last tasks are finished before it schedules more.

Comment: yes, good point. So the first executor (the scheduler) must look if all its tasks are finished before starting the next schedule, because each task is also processed by another executor. If I did not use the second executor then I would not need to look if its finished.

Comment: Correct. But you have 2 so you need to do the checking. Most of the methods of the Fixed executor will return `Future`s so just add those to a list and at the start of the logic for the Scheduled executor, check they are all complete and block until they are. Then overwrite the list with the newly scheduled task. You may want to add metrics (or logs at least) to say how long the Schedule executor is blocked for (if at all) as if it's happening regularly then that tells you that you either need more threads in the Fixed executor or you need to leave a longer gap between schedules