# How most effective add some info to list with multiple threads in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, list, concurrency

I have some task to aggregate some info from multiple links in most effective way, using multithreading. The links are at some array. By now, i have something like this solution:

```
Arrays.stream(link).parallel().forEach(link -> {
        try {
            String result = doSomeJobWithLink(link);
            System.out.println(result);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
```

And it works pretty good (job has done for 2 secs).

But I wanna not to print result in my try block, but collect results in some list (or other collection), so i did it this way:

```
List<String> resultList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
Arrays.stream(link).parallel().forEach(link -> {
        try {
            String result = doSomeJobWithLink(link);
            resultList.add(result);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
resultList.forEach(System.out::println);
```

But it's took about 5-8 sec's instead of two. Can I speed it up someway?

Comment: Try setting the initial capacity of the resultList to the size of the input array.

Comment: yep, now it's 2 sec, thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code:

```
List<String> resultList = Arrays.stream(link).parallel().map(v -> doSomeJobWithLink(v)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Normally we avoid try-catch in stream pipe but if you must have to catch exception please read [Exception Handling in Java Streams](https://medium.com/swlh/exception-handling-in-java-streams-5947e48f671c)

And don't use `parallel` just because you can, because of additional overhead your job will take more time then without `parallel`

see [Should I always use a parallel stream when possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23370799/942391)

Answer (score 2):

When you do, `Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>())`, you put a `synchronized` on the whole list i.e any operation on the list share the same mutex even reads, this has a high performance penalty and is the limiting factor.

A better way is to just collect to a normal list, [Collector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html) guarantees an unordered concurrent reduction.

> For concurrent collectors, an implementation is free to (but not required to) implement reduction concurrently. A concurrent reduction is one where the accumulator function is called concurrently from multiple threads, using the same concurrently-modifiable result container, rather than keeping the result isolated during accumulation. A concurrent reduction should only be applied if the collector has the Collector.Characteristics.UNORDERED characteristics or if the originating data is unordered.

So the below should significantly improve performance,

```
List<String> resultList = Arrays.stream(link).parallel().map(e -> {
            try {
                return doSomeJobWithLink(e);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
            return result;
        }).filter(Objects::nonNull).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Though it is not recommended to swallow exceptions, unless that is unavoidable.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about it if the below code will improve any performance or not but I think it will be a cleaner approach to solve your problem.

```
List<String> resultList = Arrays.stream(link).parallel().map(e -> {
            String result = null;
            try {
                result = doSomeJobWithLink(e);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
            return result;
        }).filter(e -> e != null).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Returning null is always the first step towards a NPE. Dont do that. Either throw a custom exception, or return an empty list.