# Converting sum of a subset to stream that can be executed in parallel

Tags: java, java-stream

Consider the following:

```
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import java.util.stream.DoubleStream;

public class Test {

    public static double sum(double[] x, int i, int L) {
        double s = 0;
        int hi = i + L;
        while (i < hi) {
            s += x[i - 1];
            i++;
        }
        return s;
    }

    /*public static double streamSum(double[] x, int i, int L) {
        return IntStream.range(0, x.length)
                        .parallel()
                        .filter(j -> (j < i + L))
                        .mapToObj(j -> x[j - 1])
                        .sum();
    }*/

    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        double[] x = {1, 2, 3, 4};
        System.out.println(sum(x, 1, 3));

    }

}
```

`sum` above takes the array `x` and (based on 1-indexing - don't ask why, it has to be that way) takes a starting index `i` and obtains a subset of length `L`, summing over said subset. An example is given in `main` above.

How do I fix `streamSum` above so that I get the same output as `sum` except using a parallel stream?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said you wanted to sum a sub array starting at i for length L.  You should do it like this.

```
double r = IntStream.range(i, L+i)
            .parallel()
            .mapToDouble(id -> x[id-1])
            .sum();

System.out.println(r);
```

The reason to subtract 1 is to account for the 1 based index requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fix for the code in your question. You should take note of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20375622) though.

```
double r = IntStream.range(i, j)
                .parallel()
                .mapToDouble(idx -> x[idx])
                .sum();
```

An even simpler way to achieve the same result would be:

```
Arrays.stream(x, i, j).parallel().sum();
```

**Note**: if you want to sum by *length (L)* rather than an *upper bound*, just replace `j` with `i + L` in the above code. Your criteria that it should be 1-based is problematic as written, since Java arrays are 0-based by default; working with them as if they are 1-based will eventually cause an `IndexOutOfBoundException`.