# Multiple threads to calculate sums Java

Tags: multithreading

this is how I can find sum of array.
 p[i] - array of random integers, size 1000

```
sum = 0;
for (int j = 1; j < p.length; j++ ) 
    {
            sum = sum + p[j];
    }
```

my question is how can I use multiple threads to perform it faster?

Comment: You think it will be really faster?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the easiest way to parallelize a task in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016083/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-parallelize-a-task-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

Simply:

```
int sum = Arrays.stream(p).parallel().sum();
```

Comment: Although this might answer the question, I'm not sure it helps anyone understand why and how it works.